# Jython Date to String conversion

Tags: java, jython

How to print a date object 2017-09-09 as a string '2017-09-09' in jython?

I need to set the value [ 2017-09-09 + string ] as a string in Jython.
I tried the following :

1. str(2017-09-09)
2. print ("'" + 2017-09-09 + "'")

But it gives error.
Example :

```
package com.myexample;

public class SomeClassInJAVA(){ 
    public static Date getDate(){

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = sdf.parse("1972-09-09");
        return d;
    }
}
```

//Jython Script

```
from com.myexample import SomeClassInJAVA
d = SomeClassInJAVA.getDate() 
print d  //prints d as 1972-09-09
print str(d) //returns error
print "'" + d + "'"
```

Assuming that I convert the recived date back to Java string in jython

```
s = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d)
print s // prints s as 1972-09-09
```

How do I convert it to '1972-09-09'

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: `2017-09-09` is not a "date" object that I'm familiar with. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I assume that you are working with instances of java.util.Date. Take a look at [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I am working on a jython script that takes an input  java.util.Date object for example say  dateObj =  2017-09-09. When storing the value in jython script , I have used SimpleDateFormat format method to convert the date object to a string of format "yyyy-MM-dd" and store it in a variable jythonDate. But when printing this jythonDate in jython script as "some string " + jythonDate , it gives me Py.TypeError.

Comment: Show us complete code that we can run. You have already been asked to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hope the above helps.

Comment: You have `s = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d)`. Doesn't `print "'" + s + "'"` produce what you want?

Comment: I have tried that. It compiles without errors but when I run, it gives me Py.TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, your conversion needs to happen *after* you get the JythonDate, not before:

```
myStr = "some string" + str(jythonDate);
```

Comment: So how do i convert the java.util.Date object 2017-09-09 to jython date?

Comment: I'm confused. If you're taking in a `java.util.Date` object in Python, you're already in `Jython`.

Comment: Java Date Object received as input in jython script is 2017-09-09 which I need to print as a string. str() does not work because of "-" in the date object. I need to get '2017-09-09' from the java date object to concatenate it with a string in jython and print.